# SQL nested order by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure that this has been asked before, but I don't know what to call it exactly to find the answer.

I have a table of categories and sub categories.  They each have an id and a parent id.  If it is a top level category, the parent id is 0.  Sub categories have the parent id set to the 
category id of it's parent.

```
category_id          # The ID for this record
category_name        # The name of the category
parent_id            # The parent ID for this category
display_order        # Order of categories within their grouping

1 A  0 0     # First primary category
2 a1 1 0     # Subcategory, parent is A, display_order is 0
3 a2 1 1
4 a3 1 2

5 B  0 1     # Second primary category
6 b1 5 0     # Subcategory, parent is B, display_order is 0
7 b2 5 1
8 b3 5 2
```

I'm trying to write an SQL query that will give me all of the categories in this order:

A, a1, a2, a3, B, b1, b2, b3

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY display_order
```

Is this possible in SQL, or will I need to use multiple queries

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: can you give an example of input data? not only output...

Comment: can the sub categories have sub categories in turn?

Comment: Added an example of what the table data looks like

Comment: is it important to retain the display_order of the main categories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this might maybe work:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY IF(parent_id, parent_id, category_id), parent_id, display_order
```

but since it can't use an index, it'll be slow. (Didn't test though, might be wrong)

The first `ORDER BY` condition sorts parents and children together; then the second one ensures the parent precedes its children; the third sorts the children among themselves.

Also, it will obviously work only in the case you directly described, where you have a two-level hierarchy.

Comment: in my test table i didn't add `A`, `B` and `C` in that order. i added `A` last. so my result from this query is B, b1, b2, b3, C, c1, c2, c3, A, a1, a2, a3. but if this can never happen, or if the order of  the main categories is uninteresting, then of course this will work. however, since there is a display_order column for the main categories as well, i interpreted the question as that order being important as well.

Comment: @davogotland: Indeed, I didn't notice `display_order` on the main categories. If that needs to be respected too, you do need a join, like in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

an answer has already been accepted, but i thought i would share my thoughts on this anyways. i tried to sort the main categories after their display_order column as well. here's my table

```
mysql> select * from categories;
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| category_id | category_name | parent_id | display_order |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|           1 | B             |         0 |             2 |
|           2 | C             |         0 |             3 |
|           3 | b2            |         1 |             2 |
|           4 | b1            |         1 |             1 |
|           5 | c3            |         2 |             3 |
|           6 | A             |         0 |             1 |
|           7 | c2            |         2 |             2 |
|           8 | b3            |         1 |             3 |
|           9 | a2            |         6 |             2 |
|          10 | a1            |         6 |             1 |
|          11 | c1            |         2 |             1 |
|          12 | a3            |         6 |             3 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

as you see, i have taken great care to add the categories in a none linear order :)

my query:

```
SELECT
    sub_id AS category_id,
    sub_name AS category_name,
    sub_parent_id AS parent_id,
    main_order + sub_order AS display_order
FROM (
    SELECT
        c1.display_order + c1.display_order * (
            SELECT
                inner_c.display_order
            FROM
                categories AS inner_c
            WHERE
                inner_c.parent_id <> 0
            ORDER BY
                inner_c.display_order DESC
            LIMIT 1) AS main_order,
        c2.display_order AS sub_order,
        c2.category_name AS sub_name,
        c2.category_id AS sub_id,
        c2.parent_id AS sub_parent_id
    FROM
        categories AS c1
    JOIN
        categories AS c2
    ON
        c1.category_id = c2.parent_id
    WHERE
        c1.parent_id = 0
    ) AS renumbered
UNION ALL
SELECT
    category_id,
    category_name,
    parent_id,
    display_order + display_order * (
        SELECT
            inner_c.display_order
        FROM
            categories AS inner_c
        WHERE
            inner_c.parent_id <> 0
        ORDER BY
            inner_c.display_order DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS display_order
FROM
    categories
WHERE
    parent_id = 0
ORDER BY
    display_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds almost identical to another I've answered with similar parent/child hierarchy while retaining child elements at same grouped level as its corresponding parent...[Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067684/sql-order-by-problem/5068136#5068136)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, I build SQL incrementally, not least because it gives me the option of testing as I go.

The first thing we need to be able to do is identify the top-level categories:

```
 SELECT category_id   AS tl_cat_id,
        category_name AS tl_cat_name,
        display_order AS tl_disp_order
   FROM Categories
  WHERE parent_id = 0;
```

Now we need to join that with the categories and subcategories to get the result:

```
SELECT t.tl_cat_id, t.cat_name, t.tl_disp_order, c.category_id, c.category_name,
       CASE WHEN c.parent_id = 0 THEN 0 ELSE c.display_order END AS disp_order
  FROM Categories AS c
  JOIN (SELECT category_id   AS tl_cat_id,
               category_name AS tl_cat_name,
               display_order AS tl_disp_order
          FROM Categories
         WHERE parent_id = 0) AS t
     ON c.tl_cat_id = t.parent_id OR (c.parent_id = 0 AND t.tl_cat_id = c.category_id)
  ORDER BY tl_disp_order, disp_order;
```

The join condition is unusual but should work; it collects rows where the parent ID is the same as the current category ID, or rows where the parent ID is 0 but the category ID is the same.  The ordering is then almost trivial - except that when you are dealing with the sub-category ordering, you want the parent item at the front of the list.  The CASE expression handles that mapping.