# MYSQL using ORDER By if, ordering categories with sub categories that can be ordered at both levels

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm looking to fix this following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `#__gdwproddise_category` 
      ORDER BY IF(`parent_id`, `parent_id`, `ordering`), 
           `parent_id`, `ordering` asc
```

So the important MYSQL fields are:

```
`multicat_id` = primary key
`parent_id`
`ordering`
```

Parent categories `parent_id` is = 0 the rest is = to the parent's `multicat_id`

Each unique `parent_id` (including =0, so parents) have there unique ordering set into the `ordering` field.

So in the ordering field you will find multiple rows with the value 1, 2, 3 etc. (each value is unique inside of each `parent_id`

```
like parent_id=0 will only have 1 row with ordering set to 1.
and parent_id=1 will only have 1 row with ordering set to 1.
etc.
```

i want to output them by like:

```
parent (ordering=1)
-child (ordering=1)
-child (ordering=2)
parent (ordering=2)
-child (ordering=1)
etc.
```

This following query seems to almost work. However the parents are not ordered by there `ordering` field.. they seem to be ordered by the primary key.

```
SELECT * FROM `#__gdwproddise_category` 
     ORDER BY IF(`parent_id`, `parent_id`, `multicat_id`), 
         `parent_id`, `ordering` asc
```

The first query I posted up top was my deduction trying to fix this one but that doesnt work... The first query works better. at least the parents and children are grouped togetter in that first one. this 2nd one un groups the parent from the childrens. the children seem to stick togetter.

I based my query off the example given in one of the answers from the following thread : 
[SQL nested order by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864397/sql-nested-order-by)

I found this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

It seem complex to use the "ltg rtg" solution from that article when the query I'm using aLmost does exactly what I want... That article seems to support infinite sub categories... my system only needs 1 level of sub categories.

Comment: The linked StackOverflow post requires them to be in order by primary key in the database. That's why it works. You need to use a more complex solution if you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to know the ordering of the parent to place a block
of child rows at the right place in the result, you will probably have
to use a self join.

The following query then seem to give the ordering you want:

```
SELECT C.* FROM categories AS C
LEFT JOIN categories AS P
ON P.multicat_id = C.parent_id
ORDER BY IF(P.multicat_ID, P.ordering, C.ordering),
         P.ordering, C.ordering;
```

It can be tested at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba095/1/0

Comment: im out of time today but ill try this tommoro morning and let you know. it looks promissing.