# How to determine 'nesting level' in a table built as adjacency list model

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, nested, firebird

I have this table where TT_PLAN_TASK_ID has the ID of its parent in TT_GROUP_ID:

[image]

This represents tree data as follows:

[image]

I want to sort the table data in the order of the tree.
I thought that if can calculate the 'nesting level' as indicated, then it's as simple as ordering on nesting level + tt_fromdate.

Thoughts/requirements:

- Number of levels is unlimited. For a limited number of levels I could just do some [repeated joins on the same table](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). [This approach looked nice too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864397/sql-nested-order-by), but again for a limited depth.
- I cannot use stored procedures (then calculating nesting level would be easy)
- Ultimately this has to work on Firebird, MS SQL, Oracle. Oracle's [CONNECT BY](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html) seems an option, but that does not solve it for the other two.
- When group nodes are on the same level and their starting dates are equal, their order is irrelevant (IDs 225 and 226 in the tree view both start at 28-4-2012, 226 can come before or after 225)
- Speed is not important, it's for a one time conversion and I don't expect customers to have 20+ levels
- [edit] I just notice that my second picture should count levels 0 1 2 3, not 0 1 2 3 4 ;-)

How can I calculate this nesting level?
Or where this came from: how can I sort according to the tree?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a recursive query to identify and label an unknown number of levels.  Here's an example of how to produce it in tsql (sql-server) syntax.  I leave it to you to formulate the other database queries, but all technologies have a reasonable equivalent.

```
WITH tmpCTE (all_other_fields, TT_PLAN_TASK_ID, TT_GROUP_ID, [level]) as
(

    SELECT all_other_fields, TT_PLAN_TASK_ID, TT_GROUP_ID, 0 as [level]
    FROM #myTable
    WHERE TT_GROUP_ID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.all_other_fields, t.TT_PLAN_TASK_ID, t.TT_GROUP_ID, [level] + 1
        FROM #myTable t
            INNER JOIN tmpCTE cte
                ON t.TT_GROUP_ID = cte.TT_PLAN_TASK_ID

)

SELECT * FROM tmpCTE order by level
```

However, I think you'll find that this isn't enough to produce the order you're trying to create.  You need to send along some kind of 'full address' that contains a rows entire 'level ancestry' of sortable values.  Consider this list

```
PARENT - A
 child 1
 child 4
 child 9

PARENT - B
 child 2
 child 3
```

'child 2' and 'child 3'  are lower than 'child 4' and 'child 9'  -- because they are children of a later parent node.  So you have to bring along some kind of code or metadata to make the sort work properly.

All in all, this kind of ordering and formatting is not the forte of relational database.  It seems to me, since you need to connect to so many different datasources, that this kind of work would be better handled in the application layer.  There you will have the flexibility to talk to multiple database sources and a host of tree-view controls and collections already built for the sort of iteration you want to do -- along with a great deal of additional functionality.

Comment: As far as I can tell for Firebird the only real difference would be `WITH RECURSIVE` instead of just `WITH`

Answer (score 1):

If you can bound the level statically, then a query that unrolls all the possibilities will work.

This is not very elegant and could be resolved by adding helper rows that identifies the higher levels. 
If you pass through the table and insert rows for each pair of related rows in the table (level 0-level 1, level 1-level 2) into a single row (level 0-level 2) then when the iteration adds no more rows, then each top to bottom link is established and can be used.

You can also keep a level indicator in each element and increment this if the parent element's indicator increases. The result is the same as the additional rows, but uses less data. In contrast, the helper rows can be used to identify all parents in effectively linear time.

Answer (score 0):

[OP:] The two answers so far are not not *the* answer, so I'm posting my current solution and not voting any answer as the correct one (upvoting the others for their helpful suggestions).

I'm programming in Delphi where I have a TClientDataset which allows me to do the following:

1. Add three extra (fkInternalCalc) fields TT_LEVEL (int), TT_DATEORDER (int), TT_SORTSTRING (string)
2. Go through the dataset, use a cloned cursor to look up parent, determine the nesting level for each record, put it in TT_LEVEL
3. Sort the data on TT_LEVEL, TT_FROMDATE, TT_PLAN_TASK_ID, then for each level fill TT_DATEORDER with an integer value 0,1,... We are essentially just converting the date to its order, and including the TT_PLAN_TASK_ID in the sort order is just to guarantee an unambiguous order when two records on the same level have the same start date
4. Sort the data on TT_LEVEL,TT_DATEORDER. Go through the dataset again. Put level + dateorder in TT_SORTSTRING. Now find all parents again and prepend their level + dateorder to TT_SORTSTRING. You end up with something like '00-00-01-00-02-01', meaning (from right to left) 'level 2, dateorder 1' with parent 'level 1, dateorder 0' with parent 'level 0, dateorder 0'. Make sure the strings have all equal lengths, the hyphen is only for readability.
5. Sort on TT_SORTSTRING, fill in TT_TASKORDER 0,1,2...
6. Throw away the 3 extra fields

This is an easy to understand algorithm so maybe it's useful to others too.
Note that by doing this I have 'circumvented' my 'no stored procedures' requirement, because this is essentially something you could do in a stored procedure.
I think this solution has one drawback, the parent lookups are repeated in step 4, but for my datasets that's not a problem.

[Added]
We have implemented this code in another part of the program as well: it makes it easy for a user to re-order his tree to an initial state when he feels he has made a mess dragging all the tree nodes around ;-) Therefore I have dropped the 4th requirement "When group nodes are on the same level and their starting dates are equal, their order is irrelevant". I now sort strictly on date as well (in step 3) to prevent ambiguous solutions.

Comment: This is essentially one pass of the second suggestion that I made. It will work provided your data is lexicographically ordered to start with. If not, you will need multiple passes to cater for the possible unknown level of parent rows until the data filters down from the top of the tree.

Comment: You said that you can not use stored procedures but can you execute a script from your Delphi application?

Comment: @Wodzu I'm using a mix of straight SQL statements that I send to the server, and manipulation of TClientDataset data, for which the update SQL statements are automatically generated 'behind the scenes'. Delphi also has stored procedure objects which point to a stored procedure in the RDBMS, but that option I couldn't use.

Comment: By "SQL Script" I mean a few SQL statements that can be executed in the same SQL [code block](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html). The thing you want is doable but few queries would have to be used and probably a temporary table. Would such solution satisfy you?

Comment: @Wodzu Yes I can. Note that I already have 'a' solution in my production code (which is only 'one time use' code for conversion in a program upgrade) so I doubt that I will spend time on investigating an alternative solution (for 3 RDBMSs)