# Nested order by in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

Could you please help me about the counterpart SQL server solution that mentioned in the link below for mysql:

[SQL nested order by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864397/sql-nested-order-by/32049258#32049258)

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY IF(parent_id, parent_id, category_id), parent_id, display_order
```

Comment: I've included the query. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: Google: `Case when statement`

Comment: Thanks Felix. @FutbolFan I googled a lot about the subject but all of them just discuss about case and conditions. But in the link within my question, there isn't any case and condition. Just by using the statement "ORDER BY IF(parent_id, parent_id, category_id), parent_id, display_order" all of the records are nested ordered by the specified grouping columns. I don't want select a column for sorting I want all of the grouping columns to be nested sorted. I tested the solution within link and it is OK but I can't do that in SQL server.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of `IF` statement: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `IF(a, b, c)` function means return `b` if `a` is non-null and non-zero, else return `c`.

With `IF(a, a, b)`, it really means return `a` if non-null and non-zero, else return `b`. Since you're only using the non-null check, this is what `COALESCE(a, b)` does too, and `COALESCE` is supported by most DBMS, including SQL Server.

This should therefore work on both MySQL and SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent_id, category_id) -- sort parents and children together
       , COALESCE(parent_id, 0) -- sort parent before children
       , display_order -- sorts children among themselves
```

**Updated:**
The above was assuming a good data model with foreign keys, not a data model with `0` values indicating "no parent".

Since `COALESCE` only checks for null, you'll need to use the `CASE` syntax. This will also work on most DBMS.

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY CASE WHEN parent_id <> 0 THEN parent_id ELSE category_id END
       , parent_id
       , display_order
```