# sql parent child tree with sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assuming this table

```
ParentId    ChildId    SortOrder
---------------------------------
0           1          0
1           2          1
2           3          1
2           4          2
2           6          3
1           7          2
1           9          3
9           10         1
9           12         2
```

how would i write a simple CTE (or another type of query) that would return them parent/child relationships at any level but keeping the sort-order for all child-items below the parent.

basically, this would be a simple tree-view with sub-items ordered by a specific sort-order.

sql server 2008 is the db

update:
there can be infinite parent/child levels - i tried some examples from other stack question/answers but none included a sortorder at the child level.

an example result should be:

```
parent (sort 0)
    child (sort 1)
    child (sort 2)
    child (sort 3)
        child-child (sort 1)
    child (sort 4)
        child-child (sort 1)
        child-child (sort 2)
```

etc.

hope this makes sense - maybe i'm looking at this wrong and this sort of result is better to be constructed within the mid-tier?

anyway, any feedback is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you give an example of what the results are meant to look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recursive CTE with special sort override. Note the sort override in the children of 2 (I modified the source table slightly to test this ability)

```
declare @relations table(ParentID int, ChildID int, SortOrder int, treeID int);

insert into @relations values
(0,1,0,0), (1,2,1,0), (2,3,2,0), (2,4,1,0), (2,6,3,0), (1,7,2,0), (1,9,3,0), (9,10,1,0), (9,12,2,0) --tree 0
, (0,1,0,1), (1,2,1,1), (2,3,2,1), (2,4,1,1), (2,6,3,1), (1,7,2,1), (1,9,3,1), (9,10,1,1), (9,12,2,1) --tree 1

; with cte(ParentId,ChildId,SortOrder,depth,agg,treeID) as (
    select null,ParentId,SortOrder,0
    , right('0000000'+CAST(treeID as varchar(max)),7)
        +right('0000000'+CAST(SortOrder as varchar(max)),7)
    , treeID
    from @relations where ParentId=0
    union all
    select cte.ChildId,r.ChildId,r.SortOrder,cte.depth+1
    , cte.agg
        +right('0000000'+CAST(r.treeID as varchar(max)),7)
        +right('0000000'+CAST(r.SortOrder as varchar(max)),7)
        +right('0000000'+CAST(r.ChildId as varchar(max)),7)
    , r.treeID
    from cte
    inner join @relations r on r.ParentID=cte.ChildId
    where cte.depth<32767
    and r.treeID=cte.treeID
)
select
tree=case depth when 1 then cast(ParentID as varchar(30))+' (sort '+cast(SortOrder as varchar(30))+')'
    else REPLICATE(CHAR(9),depth-1)
        + cast(ChildId as varchar(30))+' (sort '+cast(SortOrder as varchar(30))+')'
    end
from cte
where depth>0
order by agg
option (maxrecursion 32767);
```

Result:

```
tree
--------------------------------------------------
0 (sort 0)
    2 (sort 1)
        4 (sort 1)
        3 (sort 2)
        6 (sort 3)
    7 (sort 2)
    9 (sort 3)
        10 (sort 1)
        12 (sort 2)
0 (sort 0)
    2 (sort 1)
        4 (sort 1)
        3 (sort 2)
        6 (sort 3)
    7 (sort 2)
    9 (sort 3)
        10 (sort 1)
        12 (sort 2)
```

Comment: wow - this is going to take a bit of time to study :) thanks for the great answer

Comment: Hey John - using your example here and struggling with something (probably trivial). How would I modify this statement so that I can store multiple trees in the table? meaning, this currently works great if I only have ONE master root (where parentid = 0), what if i wanted to store a seperate tree (parentid = 0 as well) and get the three below it using "from @relations where ParentId=0 and childid = 45) - currently this does not seem to work with this statement? hope this makes sense

Comment: Hi Andre. Looks like you like challenging problems:)
This may be bit of a contrivance, but I added a 0-based treeID to allow for multiple matching roots. I modified the above solution to show two outwardly identical trees that are distinguished only by their treeIDs.

Answer (score 0):

sounds almost identical to another I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067684/sql-order-by-problem/5068136#5068136)  You'll have to alter the order by a little.