# manage and dynamic create hierarchical data in database with efficiently

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sorting, hierarchical-data

I am new for sql . It that  that any best suited to manage and dynamic create hierarchical data in database with efficiently and simply way?
Say for a sample , I am using grid view to view hierarchical data. My grid view need to display like below.

```
Red             <---Fruit 1
   Apple
   strawberry

Yellow          <-----Fruit 2
   banana
      Papaya
```

Please assist me how to design database structure in this scenario. On the other hand, how can I perform sorting also. For example:
I change the sequence number becoming

```
   Yellow          <-----Fruit 2 become Fruit 1
       banana
          Papaya

    Red             <---Fruit 1 become Fruit 2
       Apple
       strawberry
```

Here is my table(parent and child column)

```
Parent   Child
null      Red
Red       Apple
Red       Strawberry
null      Yellow
Yellow    banana
banana    papaya
```

Please guild me some idea and provide me some example. THanks

Comment: What's your programming language ?

Comment: Is your hierarchy fixed or it can be more nested ?

Comment: Ya. is it posible? it may be more nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer to a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676637/sql-parent-child-tree-with-sort-order/9677812#9677812). Solution used a recursive CTE. This solution also involved an id column, and an additional sort key column, which you could add to your source table (or query) for custom sorting.

Comment: OP is asking to shot in Interface.