# Walk parent/child tree with recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am stuck with a cte,
I want a query where in first parent is null.
and child of pervious parent, will be the parent of next, and so on.

```
WITH RESULT (PARENT,CHILD,TNAME,LEVEL)
AS
(
--anchor
 SELECT E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY,E.M_GENERAL_KEY,E.NAME ,0 AS LEVEL
  FROM RPT_SYN_M_GENERAL AS E 
 WHERE E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY IS NULL
 UNION ALL
 --outer
 SELECT e.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY,E.M_GENERAL_KEY,e.NAME ,LEVEL +1
 FROM RPT_SYN_M_GENERAL AS E
 INNER JOIN RESULT AS D  
 ON E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY=D.CHILD 
)
SELECT PARENT,CHILD,TNAME,LEVEL FROM RESULT as d
order by PARENT,CHILD
```

The above mentioned is my query.
Please help me to iterate through last child.

The output I have is:

```
 PARENT CHILD   TNAME               LEVEL
  NULL  0       ACCOUNT_MASTER        0
   0    1       LIABILITIES           1
   0    2       ASSETS                1
   0    3       INCOME                1
   0    4       EXPENSE               1
   0    15003   POLISHED DIAMOND      1
   0    15004   DEMO                  1
   0    15005   DEMO ( FACTORY        1
   1    238     CAPITAL A/C.          2
   1    1067    PROVISION             2
   1    1284    SECURED LOANS         2 
   1    2968    UNSECURED LOANS       2
   1    3535    SHARE HOLDERS         2
   2    484     FIXED ASSETS A/C      2
   2    3301    INVESTMENTS           2
   2    4858    CURRENT ASSETS        2
   2    4859    LOANS ADVANCES        2
   3    867     OTHER INCOME          2
   3    1246    SALES                 2
```

The Output I desire is:

```
 PARENT      CHILD  TNAME             LEVEL
   null      0                          0
    0        1                          1 
    1        238                        2
   238       982                        3
   982       26                         4
   982       894                        4        
   982       1321                       4
   238       7757                       3
   7757      7521                       4
```

Comment: It looks like you'll need to publish a sample of RPT_SYN_M_GENERAL

Comment: can u please take a demo view and try doing it your way. it should have parent key,child key ,level

Comment: Please would you supply a sample of your input table.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your underlying tables, I can't test any suggestions. But, see what happens if you swtich parent and child in the outer query:

```
WITH RESULT (PARENT,CHILD,TNAME,LEVEL)
AS
(
--anchor
 SELECT E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY,E.M_GENERAL_KEY,E.NAME ,0 AS LEVEL
  FROM RPT_SYN_M_GENERAL AS E 
 WHERE E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY IS NULL
 UNION ALL
 --outer
 SELECT D.CHILD,D.PARENT,e.NAME ,LEVEL +1 --switched parent/child
 FROM RPT_SYN_M_GENERAL AS E
 INNER JOIN RESULT AS D  
 ON E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY=D.CHILD 
WHERE LEVEL<100
)
SELECT PARENT,CHILD,TNAME,LEVEL FROM RESULT as d
order by PARENT,CHILD
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply John..
It shows 
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: I did try doing this before, but it dint work..
i want to select a parent and child.
the next record should be the one where
the child of previous record should be the parent.
and the same thing continues untill all the child gets iterated.

Comment: Maybe it helps to refer to the PARENT and CHILD aliases explicitly. Also note the LEVEL limiter in place.

Comment: i am still not getting the output. :(

Comment: it shows parent null child 0..and rest 7 rows with parent 0 and child null

Comment: Hey i have got solution to it.
I did create a function.
can u please let me know how to use order by in anchor query as well as outer query

Comment: Great! Go ahead & update your code with the new function. Also, what max depth are you getting?

Comment: With regards to sorting the parent/child tree relationship, check out [sql parent child tree with sort order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676637/sql-parent-child-tree-with-sort-order/9677812#9677812)

Answer (score 0):

For the output you specify, the rows in your CTE would need to be ranked and then you just filter for rows ranked 1 in each iteration.

```
WITH RESULT (ROW_RANK, PARENT,CHILD,TNAME,[LEVEL])
AS
(
--anchor
 SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY E.M_GENERAL_KEY), E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY,E.M_GENERAL_KEY,E.NAME ,0 AS [LEVEL]
  FROM RPT_SYN_M_GENERAL AS E 
 WHERE E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY IS NULL
 UNION ALL
 --outer
 SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY E.M_GENERAL_KEY), E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY,E.M_GENERAL_KEY,E.NAME, D.[LEVEL] +1 
 FROM RPT_SYN_M_GENERAL AS E
 INNER JOIN RESULT AS D  
 ON E.PARENT_GENERAL_KEY=D.CHILD AND ROW_RANK = 1
)
SELECT PARENT,CHILD,TNAME,LEVEL FROM RESULT as d
WHERE ROW_RANK = 1
order by PARENT,CHILD
```