# recursion in sql server in multi level

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create stored procedure that call recursion function, each time it will execute update statement.

I have a table called `document`

```
documentId   folderId
----------   --------
1222         1
1256         2
1257         3
```

And a `folder` table:

```
folderId    parentFolder
--------    -----------
1             5
2             1
3             2 
5             null
```

My stored procedure will delete folder number (1), when it has been deleted, it should move all document in folder 1 and sub folder of 1 to the parent folder of 1.

How to do that?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_deleteSubFolderDocument
(
@folderId INT ,
@newFolderId INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @count2 int 
SET @count2=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tbl_document_folder WHERE parent_folder=@folderId)
UPDATE tbl_document SET folder_id=@newFolderId WHERE folder_id=@folderId

IF(@count2 !=0)
BEGIN
DECLARE @table TABLE(id INT IDENTITY(1,1),folderId INT,parentFolder int  )
INSERT INTO @table(folderId,parentFolder)
SELECT folder_id,parent_folder FROM dbo.tbl_document_folder WHERE parent_folder=folder_id
DECLARE @index INT =0
WHILE @index<@count2
BEGIN
SET @index=@index+1
RETURN fn_deleteSubFolderDocument((SELECT folderId FROM @table WHERE id=@index),(SELECT parentFolder FROM @table WHERE id=@index ))
END

END 

END
GO
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I would rather have this logic im my web tier than achieve this using SQL

Comment: Folder 1 doesn' have a parent folder?! What should happen with documentiD 1222? What should happen with parentFolder of FolderID 2?

Comment: so given the example you've descibed you'd expect all the documants to be in Folder 5 (as 5 is the parent of 1 > 1 is the parent of 2 > and 2 is the parent of 3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to replicate in SQLfiddle to try to walk down through the tree of dependencies you've illustrated as I think your problem is similar to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291945/walk-parent-child-tree-with-recursive-cte)

ok - this will walk down your tree for you:

```
create table document
(
  [documentId] int,
  [folderId] int
)
insert into document
values
(1222, 1),
(1256, 2),
(1257, 3)


create table folder
(
  [folderId] int,
  [parentFolder] int null
)
insert into folder
values
(1, 5),
(2, 1),
(3, 2),
(5, null)
```

Here is the recirsive CTE that walks down the tree and finds the subfolders of subfolders of subfolders ...

```
DECLARE @folderToDelete int = 1

;WITH RESULT (folders,LEVEL)
  AS
  (
  --anchor
   SELECT
      folderId [folders]
      ,0 AS LEVEL
   FROM folder AS E 
   WHERE folderId = @folderToDelete

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
      E.folderId [folders]
      ,LEVEL +1 --switched parent/child
  FROM 
      folder AS E
      INNER JOIN RESULT AS D  
         ON 
          E.parentFolder=D.folders 
  --WHERE LEVEL < 100
  )
SELECT *
FROM RESULT OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)
```

I've saved a live example [here on SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69049/3)

Once you have this set of folders it should be easy enough to find all the associated documents that you need to move

Referring to this [article by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/29/sql-server-sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte-part-2-maxrecursion-prevent-cte-infinite-loop/) I've amended the way the loop detects it's maximum. Without any sort of catch for the maximum if the loop carried on past 100 iterations the server would error but according to this article it looks like MAXRECURSION  can be set as high as 32767....hopefully your file structure isn't that complex!

Comment: great answer .. thank you very much , but this line for what (WHERE LEVEL < 100
)

Comment: recursive cte's have a limit on the number of loops they will complete. Can't remember the exact number but I belive it is about 120...at that point it will error; so this line will mean it won't error. Are you ever likely to need it to go beyond 100? I'll edit the answer slightly

Comment: just change the '100' in the script to the max loops you require

Answer (score 0):

1. you did not mention the case, what if there is no parent folder i-e folder1 has parent id null?
2. Since this is in the database and  you are only deleting folders, merely few update statements shall be enough for the work

   ```
   // Update the documents parent which were in folder1   
   Update document SET folderId=@newFolderID Where folderID = @oldFolderID 

   // Update the parent in Folder table where parentid =1 
   Update folder SET parentId=@newFolderID Where parentID = @oldFolderID 

   // Update the folder in Folder table where parentid =1 
   Update folder SET folderId=@newFolderID Where folderID = @oldFolderID
   ```

except for these does not handle a folder without parent.

Comment: if id delete folder 1 .. all documents in folder 1 and folder 2 and folder 3 should moved to folder 5 (the parent of deleted folder)

Comment: @Haneen, that doesn't answer the questions we have, you simply shifted the problem. What should happen if you delete folder 5?

Comment: just to rephrase the question, @Haneen , what if there is only one folder say `folder5` containing all documents and you delete it ??

Comment: folder number 5 will not deleted at all i can handle this because it is the basic parent and it will not deleted .. 
when delete folder 1  i want to replace folder id in document table(1,2,3) with 5 .. (the  parent folder id of deleted folder  )

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:

1. select the tree of the descendants, using the[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) recursive common table expression
2. update all the documents, which folder is contained in the provded list
3. delete the old folder.

Of course, there are opened issues which you didnt answer, such as what to do with the sub-folders themsevles, but it should be easy to solve, using the same recursive CTE technique

```
--create recursive cte
with childfolders(folderID, parentFolder)
as
{
    --stop when you reach the first level
    select * from folder where parentFolderID = @oldFolderId

    --get the other levels
    select folder.folderId, folder.parentFolderId
     from folder folder inner join childFolders children on children.folderId
     = folder.parentFolderId
}

--update
update document set folderId = @newFolderId
where folderId in (select folderId from childFolders)

--delete
delete from folder where folderId= @oldFolderId
```

Comment: all sub folder will deleted also ,, i want only the documents in deleted folder and sub folder to moved to parent folder .

Comment: then u can use the same CTE to delete all the folders in the hierarchy (delete from folders where folderId in childfolders)

Comment: but if you see when i will call the SP that will delete folder number 1,, i will send folder id only to stored procedure (1),, and the sp will discover that 5 is parent and folder number (2,3) are childs of 1 ,,

Comment: then it will update folder id that is in document folder to 5(the parent of deleted folder) and all folder id (2,3) children of 1 update them to 5 .

Comment: this is exactly what my code is doing. you should try some of the answers provided (at least another one suggests using cte) instead of explaining to us why do you think our answers are not good.

Comment: no i dont think that you answers not good .. i will try it ,,i want to explain only ,, thank you very much :)