Is there a way to retrieve a parent child tree from a single table, with multiple roots and a child_order column?
I have a table that looks like this:
CREATE TABLE tbl 
(
    id int,
    parent_id int,
    child_order int,
    name varchar(20)
)

Take this as a sample dataset:
1   NULL    0   BtVS
2   NULL    1   Star Trek
3   1       0   Buffy
4   1       1   Willow
5   1       2   Xander
6   1       3   Giles
7   2       0   Kirk
8   2       1   Spock
9   2       2   McCoy
10  2       3   Uhura
11  3       0   Strength
12  3       1   Speed
13  3       2   Dreams
14  4       0   Tech
15  4       1   Magic
16  4       2   Dreams
17  5       0   Heart
18  5       1   Humor
19  5       2   Loyalty
20  6       0   Wisdom
21  6       1   Training
22  6       2   Guidance
23  7       0   Leadership
24  7       1   Independence
25  7       2   Courage
26  8       0   Logic
27  8       1   Strength
28  8       2   Nerve Pinch
29  9       0   Healing
30  9       1   Sarcasm
31  9       2   Friendship
32  10      0   Communications
33  10      1   Languages
34  10      2   Music

I want it to output like this:
1   1   BtVS
3   2       Buffy
11  3           Strength
12  3           Speed
13  3           Dreams
4   2       Willow
14  3           Tech
15  3           Magic
16  3           Dreams
5   2       Xander
17  3           Heart
18  3           Humor
19  3           Loyalty
6   2       Giles
20  3           Wisdom
21  3           Training
22  3           Guidance
2   1   Star Trek
7   2       Kirk
23  3           Leadership
24  3           Independence
25  3           Courage
8   2       Spock
26  3           Logic
27  3           Strength
28  3           Nerve Pinch
9   2       McCoy
29  3           Healing
30  3           Sarcasm
31  3           Friendship
10  2       Uhura
32  3           Communications
33  3           Languages
34  3           Music

Giving me the id column, the report level, and the name column. But in order, like this. The child_order column may be discontinuous. Meaning that there might be 4 children of a single parent with child_orders of 0, 1, 5 and 9. It's only their relative order that matters. And there can be more than 10 children, so I can't rely on the number of digits in the child_order.
I've tried working with CTEs, but I haven't found a way to make it work with multiple roots, and I haven't found a way to make it work with the child_order column, because ORDER BY is not valid inside a CTE.
Is there a way to accomplish this that's reasonable? I've thought about using powers of 10 for each report level, and adding the hierarchy to get a sort value, but like I said, you can have two digit child_orders, which would mess that up.

"I've tried working with CTEs" So where is this try???  I don't see it here ...

Are you just after an rCTE with "added" formatting to your dataset (which should probably be done in the presentation layer)?

Here is a fiddle to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/YJV6CYjM

this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676637/sql-parent-child-tree-with-sort-order

I think you need an example where the child order is not in sync with the ID. For example try any solution with 2 Language and 1 Music  (instead of  1 Language and 2 Music).

Seems like you can achieve this with an rCTE, as I mentioned. To get the ordering, you can create a hierarchyid (like) string, and then CONVERT that to said data type in the ORDER BY:
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT t.id,
           t.name,
           t.child_order,
           0 AS Level,
           CONVERT(varchar(8000),CONCAT('/',t.id,'/')) AS hid --or use child_order
    FROM dbo.tbl t
    WHERE t.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id,
           t.name,
           t.child_order,
           r.Level + 1,
           CONVERT(varchar(8000),CONCAT(r.hid,t.id,'/')) --or use child_order
    FROM dbo.tbl t
         JOIN rCTE r ON t.parent_id = r.id)
SELECT r.id,
       r.child_order,
       CONCAT(REPLICATE(CHAR(9),r.Level),r.name) AS name
FROM rCTE r
ORDER BY CONVERT(hierarchyid,r.hid);


@BartMcEndree not everything needs a fiddle... (Especially when you are relicensing the content under CC0.)

This works, the only problem is that hierarchy orders by IDs, not by eventual sort order which OP has

It's in the correct order in my environment, @siggemannen .

yeah, but if you change sort order for Communications to 66 it will still become first

So if you change the sample data the results change? Yes, @siggemannen , of course they will... I'm not sure of your point. We can only work with the data we have.

I think the code should bin the sort by hierarchyid because it relies on internal IDs, and instead do the sort by the level + child_order, which is the order the OP seem to look after.

Tou can just change t.id to t.child_order in the expression for hid, and that'll "solve" that scenario, @siggemannen .

Yeah, that's a good workaround!

But I want it to both sort in child_order and include the id in the recordset. I don't know anything about hierarchyid, but will it allow that?

Sorry, I understand now. And it works great. Thanks to both of you!

Here's a version which accounts to sorting preferences:
WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (1, NULL, 0, N'BtVS')
        ,   (2, NULL, 1, N'Star Trek')
        ,   (3, 1, 0, N'Buffy')
        ,   (4, 1, 1, N'Willow')
        ,   (5, 1, 2, N'Xander')
        ,   (6, 1, 3, N'Giles')
        ,   (7, 2, 0, N'Kirk')
        ,   (8, 2, 1, N'Spock')
        ,   (9, 2, 2, N'McCoy')
        ,   (10, 2, 3, N'Uhura')
        ,   (11, 3, 0, N'Strength')
        ,   (12, 3, 1, N'Speed')
        ,   (13, 3, 2, N'Dreams')
        ,   (14, 4, 0, N'Tech')
        ,   (15, 4, 1, N'Magic')
        ,   (16, 4, 2, N'Dreams')
        ,   (17, 5, 0, N'Heart')
        ,   (18, 5, 1, N'Humor')
        ,   (19, 5, 2, N'Loyalty')
        ,   (20, 6, 0, N'Wisdom')
        ,   (21, 6, 1, N'Training')
        ,   (22, 6, 2, N'Guidance')
        ,   (23, 7, 0, N'Leadership')
        ,   (24, 7, 1, N'Independence')
        ,   (25, 7, 2, N'Courage')
        ,   (26, 8, 440, N'Logic')
        ,   (27, 8, 1, N'Strength')
        ,   (28, 8, 2, N'Nerve Pinch')
        ,   (29, 9, 0, N'Healing')
        ,   (30, 9, 1, N'Sarcasm')
        ,   (31, 9, 2, N'Friendship')
        ,   (32, 10, 1, N'Communications')
        ,   (33, 10, 0, N'Languages')
        ,   (34, 10, 5, N'Music')
    ) t (id,parent_id,child_order,name)
)
, cte AS (
    SELECT  id
    ,   name, 1 AS level
    ,   cast(RIGHT(replicate('0', 10) + cast(child_order AS varchar(10)), 10) AS nvarchar(max)) AS sortorder
    FROM    data
    WHERE   parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  d.id
    ,   d.name, level + 1
    ,   c.sortorder + RIGHT(replicate('0', 10) + cast(d.child_order AS varchar(10)), 10) AS sortorder
    FROM    cte c
    INNER JOIN data d
        ON  d.parent_id = c.id
    )
SELECT  *
,   REPLICATE('-', level * 4) + name AS tree
FROM    cte
ORDER BY sortorder

I've changed the example data slightly. The sorting is done by a padded string which keeps expanding for each level.
